# How to filter AWS CloudWatch logs using cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to write a query to filter CW logs using the cli.

In the console I am able to filter the logs using this:

```
{($.latencies.request >15000) && ($.request.uri = "some/api/call")}
```

but if I write a query on the cli

```
    queryId=$(aws logs start-query \
        --log-group-name "${loggroup}" \
        --start-time `date -jnRu -v-1d +%s` \
        --end-time `date +%s` \
        --query-string "fields @timestamp, @message 
    | parse @message "$.latencies.request>15000, request.uri = 'some/api/call'"
    | limit 20" | jq --raw-output '.queryId'
)
echo "querying loggroup ${loggroup} \n"
aws logs get-query-results \
    --query-id $queryId --output text
```

but gives an error `MalformedQueryException`

how to fix this?

====UPDATE

using `filter-log-events` now throws an error in the call

```
aws_cw_filter_logs(){
  echo "filtering logs using a query  \n"
  local loggroup=${1:-"myloggroup"}
  local logstream=${2:-"app/app/sdasdsadas"}     
  local query=${3:-"{($.latencies.request >15000) && ($.request.uri = "'"/some/api/"'")}"}
  aws logs filter-log-events \
  --log-group-name $loggroup \
  --log-stream-names $logstream \
  --max-items 1 \
  --output text \
  --filter-pattern $query
}
```

this is ok, wondering if there are date filtering capabilities like in the console (no trace in the docs)

Comment: On CLI, I think you can simply filter logs using "filter-log-events" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/filter-log-events.html

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `--start-time` and `--endtime` options.
See: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/filter-log-events.html